# Software to annotate EPUB files (with capability to export the annotations)

Tags: annotation, epub

I am looking for a software for Android and/or Linux to annotate EPUB files.

It should have the capability to export the annotations. Preferably in XML or other easily parsable format.

Comment: Try http://calibre-ebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible using only 1 software, but maybe you can do that this way:

1. Install [pale moon](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:stevenpusser&package=palemoon), a prerrequisite of epub reader [Lucidor](http://lucidor.org/lucidor/)
2. Install Lucidor

   ```
   wget "http://lucidor.org/get.php?id=lucidor_0.9.15-1_all.deb" -O lucidor09.deb
   sudo apt install ./lucidor09.deb
   ```
3. Make annotations in Lucidor (for a guide, look [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tips-and-tricks-using-two-best-e-readers-linux))
   and locate the file's `annotations.sqlite` path
4. Now, you have to [install R](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04) and a pair of packages

   ```
   install.packages("RSQLite")  # same for XML
   ```
5. Export annotations as xml [Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015686/how-to-open-sqlite-files), [Ref 2](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-September/175364.html)

   ```
   library("RSQLite")
   sqlite    <- dbDriver("SQLite")

   # replace with correct PATH:
   db <- dbConnect(sqlite,"/home/USERNAME/.ordbrand/lucidor/b2e53o8w.default/lucifox/annotations.sqlite")

   dfannotAnnot<-as.data.frame(dbReadTable(db,"annotations") )
   dfannotTarg<-as.data.frame(dbReadTable(db,"targets") )

   dataframe<-cbind(dfannotAnnot,dfannotTarg)

   library(XML)
   xml <- xmlTree()

   xml$addTag("document", close=FALSE)
   for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe)) {
     xml$addTag("row", close=FALSE)
     for (j in names(dataframe)) {
       xml$addTag(j, dataframe[i, j])
     }
     xml$closeTag()
   }
   #save to file
   getwd()
   cat(saveXML(xml), file="Annotations.xml")
   ```